# UK visa given with wrong dates

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I have applied for a UK VISA 3 months in advance and have mentioned that my UK arrival date is 15th Sept 2019. I also mentioned that I intend to stay for 5 months. Thus my return date will be mid Feb 2020. Now I received  my VISA from 03/07/2019 to 03/01/2020. The expiry date is prior to my intended departure date.

What should I do to get dates corrected?

Comment: Contact the high commission immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Even though you said your arrival and departure dates when you applied, the visa is usually issued form the date of approval (that explains the July date) then 6 months onwards. I have found several people with similar situations.

I recommend trying to travel earlier, but as that might be a challenge you can contact UK visas and immigration.

If you are contacting them outside of the UK here are your options for contacting them:

[image: contact options]